# Proofs on Convex Sets.

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

> Prove that the set $C:=\{ x : x+S_2 \subset S_1 \}$, with $S_1,S_2\subset \Bbb R^n$ is convex if $S_1$ is convex.

I understant that a vectorial space is a convex set. So $S_1$ and $S_2$ are both convex sets. But I do not understand how to continue with the idea.

Comment: For future reference, you might want to have a look at how to format question in LaTeX here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: No, $S_2$ is not convex.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x, y \in C$ and $0 \le t \le 1$.  You want to show $tx + (1-t)y \in C$, i.e. $tx + (1-t)y + S_2 \subset S_1$.
If $s_2 \in S_2$, $tx + (1-t) y + s_2 = t (x + s_2) + (1-t) (y + s_2)$ with
$x + s_2 \in S_1$ and $y + s_2 \in S_1$.  Since $S_1$ is convex, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of looking at it:

Note that $C = \{ x | x +y \in S_1 \ \forall y \in S_2 \} = \{ x | x \in S_1-\{y\} \ \forall y \in S_2 \} = \cap_{ y \in S_2} (S_1 - \{y\})$.

Each set $S_1 - \{y\}$ is convex since it is the translate of a convex
set and  since the
intersection of convex sets is convex, we see that $C$ is convex.